# How to transfer an android app containing firebase from one computer to another

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was creating an android app for a school project and i have integerated firebase into it. Later i realized that i should keep a seperate copy of my app on other computer.I once tried to copy and paste my app onto another computer and open it in android studio but it didnt go well.

Any ideas how to do this such that firebase database remains same.

Comment: There is no worry of firebase database. Cause you have to just put the **Json** file in project. Rest you can use it normally.

Comment: Just copy your project and open it in other computer. Now create debug key and put it in firebase console settings page.

Answer (score 0):

Typically people use a source control tool such as git to store their project source code.  Firebase has nothing to do with this.

Nothing changes when you copy project files to other machines.  If you are using Firebase Authentication, you will also have to copy your debug signing keys, or add the SHA1 hash of your new key to the project in the console, but this has nothing to do with your project files.